# iMac + Catalina : Needs to be shutdown manually

Tags: imac, shutdown

I have an iMac (boutght in 2019), with macOS 10.15.7 .

From one day to the next, the Shut Down did not work anymore. When I click on Apple-Menu, ShutDown, the applications seemingly close, but then I am left with an empty background and a moveable mouse cursor, but nothing else the system would react to. Of course I can do a hard shutdown then, by pressing the power button for about 14 seconds.

To research the issues further, I tried the following: Instead of doing a "Shut Down", i did a Logout to ensure that I'm really logged out, hoping that this would ensure that there are no other applications running anymore. I get the normal login screen, where I can choose between the various user accounts on the Mac, and have the row of buttons, among them one for "shutdown". When I click on it, it seems to shut down first, but immediately restarts again. Sometimes the effect is as if the screen picture "rotates" (a similar visual effect which you see when you switch between users).

Here again, I can of course force a shutdown by pressing the power button long enough, but I still wonder what's going on here.